# Pass readableStream to C binding

Tags: c, node.js, stream

Is it possible to pass a readableStream into a Node.js C binding library in some way without having to buffer it first? I'm aware of using child_process.spawn with stdin and stdout and shell commands for similar sorts of tasks but is there a way to pass in a stream directly (assuming that would be more performant than a child process and stdin/stdout)?

Thanks for any guidance!